# How to cycle through a series of images onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a page that is a div holding a grid of `img` elements. I want each image, on click, to cycle to the next image in a series of three. This will repeat on each click until the third image is clicked and it loops back to the first image.

I have considered writing this in javascript, but I am struggling to write a method that can do this without referencing specific filenames; this would be very easy if I had only one image that I wanted to cycle with two others because I could just have a conditional function that called the next image based on the current one. But I can't write that out each time for the 100+ images in the grid on the page. I essentially have a long list of `img` elements and some CSS defining the divs right now, and I'm lost as to the next step.

I'm mostly eager for someone to suggest the best language to do this in and give me a general sense of what the script would be doing and how it would interact with the `img` elements; I don't expect you to write it for me!

CSS:

```
        .grid {
            width: 980px;
            height: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        img {
            width: 200px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
```

HTML:

```
     <div class="grid">
         <img src="image1_first.jpg"></img> ...
     </div>
```

Here's where I run into trouble: I need to have three total images loaded (image1_first, image1_second, image1_third; image2_first, etc...)
but only be displaying one per spot in "grid" until clicked.

Comment: Need to see your efforts!

Comment: Write the function in javascript, without seeing the structure of your html it is virtually impossible for anyone to fully answer this.

Comment: Simple use a javascript image slider [check](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified)

Comment: You need javascript, but it would be easier with jquery. Also, don't need to store image names, just to target DOM elements... (e.g. need current, and need next, and you need total length of images, etc, etc)

Comment: Do you mean something like image sliders ?. Couldn't get what you meant by cycling in a series of 3

Comment: Added some code—thanks!

Comment: From code you have posted, you need one more container - with same width as image, if you just want ONE image shown....

Answer (score 0):

the best language would be javascript, with a bit of help from JQuery I think.
What you can do is cheating with opacity to made a fade in:
This is just an example, this code won't work.

```
in html:
img1 opacity = 1;
img2 opacity = 0;
img3 opacity = 0;
in js:
onClick {
  if (img1opacity = 1){
    img1opacity = 0;
    img2opacity = 1;
  }
}
```

ect..
For a slider you can watch how other sliders are made, it's not that hard, you put all the images side by side and change the `left` or `margin` of your element.
A cool way to slide in ALWAYS the same side is to put your images like this: 1 2 3 1, so when you're at the last one, you can easily make a `left:0;` or `margin:0;` to go to the first one without rotating in the otherside.